# libgdx Player movment dungeon crawler

Tags: libgdx, movement

The player go's throe walls and stops when theres no wall.
Code:

```
package input;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.GridPoint2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

import dungeon.Dungeon;
import player.PlayerCharacter;
import player.Player_state;

public class PlayerInputProcessor {
private PlayerCharacter player;
private Dungeon dungeon;

private final int NORTH = 0, SOUTH = 1, WEST = 2, EAST = 3;

public PlayerInputProcessor(PlayerCharacter player, Dungeon dungeon) {
    this.player = player;
    this.dungeon = dungeon;
}

public void HandleInput() {
    Vector2 pos = player.getVectorPos();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
        if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) (player.getVectorPosY() - 3) / player.getHight()), NORTH)) {
            player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() + 3);
        }
    } 
     if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
        if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) (player.getVectorPosY() - 3) / player.getHight()), SOUTH)) {
            player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() - 3);
            player.setState(Player_state.WALKING_FORWORD);
        }
    }
     if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
         if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) (player.getVectorPosX() + 3) / player.getWidth(), (int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()), EAST)) {
            player.setVectorPosX(player.getVectorPosX() + 3);
        }
    } 
     if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
         if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) (player.getVectorPosX() - 3) / player.getWidth(), (int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()), WEST)) {
            player.setVectorPosX(player.getVectorPosX() - 3);
        }
    } 

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.E)) {
        if(player.hasSword()) {
            player.sword = false;
        }
        else player.sword = true;
    }


     player.setGridPos(new GridPoint2((int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(),(int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()));

}
private Boolean canmovethere(GridPoint2 newpos, int die) {
    GridPoint2 nextpos = new GridPoint2();
    GridPoint2 nextpos2 = new GridPoint2();

    if(die == NORTH) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y + 1;
        nextpos2.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos2.y = newpos.y + 1;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(die == SOUTH) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y;
        nextpos2.x = newpos.x + 1;
        nextpos2.y = newpos.y;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(die == EAST) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x + 1;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y;
        nextpos2.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos2.y = newpos.y + 1;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable() && dungeon.getTile(nextpos2).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(die == WEST) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y;
        nextpos2.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos2.y = newpos.y - 1;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    player.setState(Player_state.STANDING);
    return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: You will probably have better luck if you clearly state your question.

Comment: "The player go's throe walls and stops when theres no wall." I need help. I can't fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your player's location should be based on your underlying data structure. The division you are doing to get the next tile location has me a little worried about what cell you are actually looking at for next tile.

If `Dungeon` is all in integer values for tile locations (which makes sense), you are almost certainly having integer math problems when you are trying to find the next tile. It's hard to tell without the implementation of `Dungeon` included in your question.

If I were you, I would consider flipping your data around and having your player position be solid integers, so you always know exactly what tile your player is supposed to be at, and doing math to figure out where the player should render on screen.

But my gut feeling is that this all boils down to integer math rounding -- I'd be able to update this answer if you post your `Dungeon` code so I can get a better idea of how this is all playing together.

**Edit:**

There are a lot of what look to be copy/paste errors in your `canMoveThere` function.

1) You are setting nextpos2 in all 4 cases, but only using it in the `EAST` case. (Are you sure you only want to move east if both `nextpos` and `nextpos2` are passable?)

2) You are incorrectly setting the coordinates on `nextpos` in most of your situations.
 - `NORTH` looks ok
 - `SOUTH` is only incrementing the `x` on `newpos2` and not touching `nextpos`
 - `EAST` is modifying both `x` and `y`, as well as being the only case that checks `isPassable()` for both `nextpos` and `nextpos2`
 - `WEST` is only incrementing `y` on `newpos2` and not touching `nextpos`

The problem is certainly in the logic of `canmovethere`. I believe your function should look more like this:

```
private Boolean canmovethere(GridPoint2 newpos, int die) {
    GridPoint2 nextpos = new GridPoint2();

    if(die == NORTH) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y + 1;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(die == SOUTH) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y - 1;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(die == EAST) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x + 1;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(die == WEST) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x - 1;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    player.setState(Player_state.STANDING);
    return false;
}
```

I removed `nextpos2` as it was only used in the `EAST` case, and seemed unneeded. If you indeed intended for east to behave differently, just add that back in and make sure you are adjusting the correct values.

**Edit 2:**

There is another copy/paste error in your south logic, it looks like you have a minus where you should have a plus. Note the `- 3` in both the `UP` and `DOWN` call to `canmovethere()`:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
    if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) (player.getVectorPosY() - 3) / player.getHight()), NORTH)) {
        player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() + 3);
    }
} 
 if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
    if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) (player.getVectorPosY() - 3) / player.getHight()), SOUTH)) {
        player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() - 3);
        player.setState(Player_state.WALKING_FORWORD);
    }
}
```

I think one piece that is contributing to the confusion after looking at this more and more: You seem to be accounting for the direction the player is trying to move twice. Once in the call to `canmovethere()`:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
    if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) (player.getVectorPosY() - 3) / player.getHight()), NORTH)) {
        player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() + 3);
    }
}
```

(Noting the `(int) (player.getVectorPosY() - 3)` specifically)

and once inside the `canmovethere()` function:

```
if(die == NORTH) {
        nextpos.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos.y = newpos.y + 1;
        nextpos2.x = newpos.x;
        nextpos2.y = newpos.y + 1;
        if(dungeon.getTile(nextpos).isPassable()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

(Where you are again adjusting the y position.)

You should certainly simplify this so that you only adjust the position on one side of the call. Since you currently pass a direction into your `canmovethere` function, you might as well do it there. You can probably reduce your code to look something like this:

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
    if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()), NORTH)) {
        player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() + 3);
    }
} 
 if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)) {
    if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()), SOUTH)) {
        player.setVectorPosY(player.getVectorPosY() - 3);
        player.setState(Player_state.WALKING_FORWORD);
    }
}
 if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) {
     if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth(), (int) player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()), EAST)) {
        player.setVectorPosX(player.getVectorPosX() + 3);
    }
} 
 if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) {
     if(canmovethere(new GridPoint2( (int) (player.getVectorPosX() / player.getWidth()), (int) (player.getVectorPosY() / player.getHight()), WEST)) {
        player.setVectorPosX(player.getVectorPosX() - 3);
    }
}
```

The arguments for `canmovethere()` should be changed to `canmovethere(GridPoint2 currentPos, int direction)`. You pass in your current position and what direction you are wanting to move, and the function returns true or false if you are able to do that.

Also worth noting is that you are only setting the player state to `WALKING_FORWARD` in your `DOWN` case. Not sure if this is intentional or not.

Comment: I don't want the player to be tide to a tile for position. btw i'm using GridPoint2 for tile pos.

Comment: @ThePumkinMelon I've updated my answer with a much more thorough analysis of the code you posted.

Also, I didn't realize that GridPoint2 was a thing. I will be using that in the future. I had assumed it was a class you wrote.

Comment: Your fix did not work for me. And i was debuging and i got rid of all but EAST's nextpos2 check less code.

Comment: Can you explain what you are seeing with my suggested code? Same exact problem, or are you seeing new incorrect behavior?

Comment: Your fix works for NORTH and EAST but when going WEST or SOUTH the player stops one tile before it is suppoed too.

Comment: I've updated my answer again with some more changes to simplify the code down. Please give these a try